# RediSearch Suggestions - Delete all suggestions

Tags: redis, redisearch

RediSearch Suggestions are very useful.
What I couldn't figure out: how to delete all suggestions?

The command reference explains how to add and remove words. But it looks like there is no way to remove all?

https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftsugadd

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the key that the suggestions are stored under with the regular `DEL` command.